# Extract mean raster values by fishnet in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.0, zonal-statistics, vector-grid

I have a raster of 0.25m resolution. I created a fishnet with 100*100 m in ArcGIS. I want to extract mean values of the raster from fishnet squares(100*100). I tried zonal statistics in ARC but does not help.

Comment: Have you tried zonal statistics as table?

Comment: Thanks it works! Can I somehow add  numbers to  my boxes in fishnet grid.

Comment: If you want to change your question then, while it still has no answers, please use the [edit] button to do so.